# How to append a row to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have dataframes `df1` and `df2` both with columns `["Ticker", "Adj.Factor", "Date"]`. I want to add to `df2` the complete row from `df1` if the value of "Adj.Factor" in that row in `df1` equals to `0`.

I have the following code.

```
for x in range(tot_len):
    if df1.iloc[x]['Adj.Factor'] == 0:
        df2.append(df1.iloc[x])  --> not working.
```

`

I have tried printing the values and it shows the correct output. But the values are not appended to df2.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of dataframe you are working with?

Answer (score 13):

It seems you missed an assignment. Here is a simpler solution

```
df2 = df2.append(df1[df1['Adj.Factor'] == 0])
```

##### Update since pandas 1.4.0:

`pd.DataFrame.append` is deprecated now, use `pd.concat` instead

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1[df1['Adj.Factor'] == 0]])
```

Comment: `FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.`

Comment: @AXO tnx, updated answer

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
df2 = df2.append(df1.iloc[x])
```

> `DataFrame.append(self, other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=False) → 'DataFrame`
>
> Append rows of *other* to the end of *caller*, **returning a new object.**

[REF](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append)

Comment: "Deprecated since version 1.4.0: Use [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) instead."